# Configuring multiple Rails projects with nginx, rvm, and passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, rvm, passenger

I'm using nginx, rvm and passenger to run a web server for a Rails project (i.e., project1). This project has a specific gemset defined for it. I now need to run a second project (i.e., project2) which uses a different set of gems (and has a different gemset defined). How can I accomplish that?

This is what my configuration file for nginx looks like:

```
http {
  passenger_root /var/www/project1/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.
19;
  passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/ruby;

  # ...

  server {                                                    
    listen        80;                                                     
    server_name   project1.example.com;           

    root              /var/www/project1/public;             
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env         production;      

    # ...                       

  }      

    server {                                                    
    listen        80;                                                     
    server_name   project2.example.com;           

    root              /var/www/project2/public;             
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env         production;      

    # ...                       

  }              

  # ...
}
```

project1 works as expected. However, project2 gives me missing gem errors.

```
Could not find i18n-0.6.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Note how passenger_root points to the passenger gem within project1.

Any pointers on how I can run both projects, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the [rvm documentation](https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/) there is a section on integrating with Passenger/nginx. The solution is in there and requires you to add a new file `config/setup_load_paths.rb`. Details on that file can be found in the documentation.

BTW, if you're using Rails3, bundler is a better choice for managing application specific gems than gemsets.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I'm using Rails 3 with bundler and Gemfiles. How does that change the solution?

Comment: If you bundle your gems into vendor/bundle with `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`, then they are project-specific by nature

Comment: > "..bundler is a better choice for managing application specific gems than gemsets."

I'd say that the best option is to use both. gemsets separate everything on a per project basis, whereas bundler manages the versions of gems within a given project (in the gemset for the project).